# Calling SmartContract deployed on Ropsten Test Net

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, geth, remix

I am new to smart contract development. I have a smart contract deployed on Ethereum blockchain Ropsten Test Net. I have smart contract address and ABI. I am not sure how to call functions of that smart contract from geth terminal.

1. Do i have to sync entire blockchain to call any smart contract functions deployed?  I tried syncing but it never completes. It's stuck at last 100 blocks since a week. My ether balance is showing 0 when i connect to TestNet locally.
2. Is there anyway i can do this online? calling a deployed smart contract through Remix IDE  or any other ?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preferred way to do this is to install [MetaMask](https://metamask.io) and using that with Remix.

Comment: Thanks @smarx .  Can you give me steps to do that. I installed metamask and through remix i can access metamask wallet. But the issue is i am not sure how to load the deployed contract through smart contract ABI and address  in Remix IDE ?

Comment: If you have the source code, put it in Remix, and then on the "run" tab fill in an address next to "At Address" and click that button. If you have just the ABI, then one option is to just open up the browser console and do `contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address)` and interact with it there (much like you would in the geth console).

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the purpose of deploying it to a test net though? If you're just going to reload the source code in an IDE, then why use a test net at all?